# Making text appear one character at a time [PyGame]

Tags: python, text, dialog, pygame

**I am trying to make the dialog appear one character at a time** (Like in Pokemon games and other similar).

I have searched over the internet but have not managed to find anything helpful.

I am aware of another question asked like this, but it didn't solve what I am trying to do. I know this can be done because I have seen games made with python where this has been done.

Comment: Appear in console or pygame window?

Comment: In the pygame Window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

WINDOW_WIDTH = 500
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500

pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT))

BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

def display_text_animation(string):
    text = ''
    for i in range(len(string)):
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE)
        text += string[i]
        text_surface = font.render(text, True, BLACK)
        text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
        text_rect.center = (WINDOW_WIDTH/2, WINDOW_HEIGHT/2)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(text_surface, text_rect)
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.wait(100)

def main():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

display_text_animation('Hello World!')
main()
```

NOTE: I haven't used pygame before so this may not work.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been looking everywhere for a solution. But I don't believe you haven't used pygame before considering you solved this

Comment: @Gaspump1112 I read a few pages from this book http://inventwithpython.com/makinggames.pdf to answer your question. You may want to use this resource for future projects.

Comment: Okay, I have (tried to) answer your question.  But thanks, I will look at that pdf book :)

Answer (score 0):

The below works very well. And stops any overloading of the event queue (so multiple lines or lots of text don't stall the animation). This is necessary if embedded in a simple application that doesn't handle the event queue in some other way.

```
line_space = 16
basicfont = pygame.font.SysFont('MorePerfectDOSVGA', 16)

def text_ani(str, tuple):
    x, y = tuple
    y = y*line_space ##shift text down by one line
    char = ''        ##new string that will take text one char at a time. Not the best variable name I know.
    letter = 0
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(str)):
        pygame.event.clear() ## this is very important if your event queue is not handled properly elsewhere. Alternativly pygame.event.pump() would work.
        time.sleep(0.05) ##change this for faster or slower text animation
        char = char + str[letter]
        text = basicfont.render(char, False, (2, 241, 16), (0, 0, 0)) #First tuple is text color, second tuple is background color
        textrect = text.get_rect(topleft=(x, y)) ## x, y's provided in function call. y coordinate amended by line height where needed
        screen.blit(text, textrect)
        pygame.display.update(textrect) ## update only the text just added without removing previous lines.
        count += 1
        letter += 1
        print char ## for debugging in console, comment out or delete.


text_ani('this is line number 1 ', (0, 1)) # text string and x, y coordinate tuple.
text_ani('this is line number 2', (0, 2))
text_ani('this is line number 3', (0, 3))
text_ani('', (0, 3)) # this is a blank line
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more simplistic, it creates a function which you can use whenever you want. In this example I called my function 'slow' and made it so that you need to input a string when calling it. Whatever is inputted will display character by character. The speed depends on the value near 'sleep'. Hope this helped.

```
from time import * #imports all the time functions

def slow(text): #function which displays characters one at a time
    for letters in text: #the variable goes through each character at a time
        print(letters, end = "") #current character is printed
        sleep(0.02) #insert the time between each character shown
#the for loop will move onto the next character

slow("insert text here") #instead of print, use the name of the function
```

If you run this as it is, it should output "insert text here" one character at a time.